# unique real solution to $x + e^x = 0$ has no special properties, right?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Let $a$ be the unique real number such that $a + e^a = 0$. I claim that

(1) $a$ is irrational. (Easy enough: If $a$ were rational, then write $a = p/q$ for integers $p,q$. It follows that $e^a = -a$ is rational, and hence $e^p = (e^a)^q$ is also rational. But this contradicts the fact that $e$ is transcendental.)

(2) $a$ is transcendental. (Is this true?)

(3) $a = -e^{-e^{-e^{-e^{\cdots}}}}$

Anyone know of any other properties of $a$?

Comment: +1 for the nice question. But your title is bit confusing, as any "unique" number is special.

Answer (score 1):

The constant you are describing is the negative of the omega constant. That is

$$a=-\Omega=-0.5671432\dots$$

This is easily seen with the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant#Fixed_point_representation)

$$e^{-\Omega}=\Omega$$

$$\Rightarrow e^a=-a$$

$$\Rightarrow a+e^a=0$$

In answer to your second question, $\Omega$ is known to be transcendental (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant#Transcendence)). Another definition for $\Omega$ is the real number such that

$$\Omega e^\Omega=1$$

I'll provide a proof of the third fact just to complete this question: call the power tower $x$

$$x=-e^{-e^{-e^{-e^{\cdots}}}}$$

Then

$$x=-e^{x}$$

$$\Rightarrow x+e^x=0$$

$$\Rightarrow a=x$$

Answer (score 1):

The solution is intersection of $y=x$ and $t=e^x$, which is unique and negative.
Let $$f(x)=x+e^x \implies f(0)=1>0, f(-1)=-1+e^{-1}<0$$. so the solution $(x=x_0)$ lies in $(-1,0)$. Numerically it is $x_0==0.5671..$